# Как очистить или остановить поток аудио предыдущего потока?

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

Все просто, есть `ListView` и несколько пунктов, также есть `MediaPlayer`, который воспроизводит потоковое аудио при клике на пункты. Проблема в том что аудио накладывается друг на друга. Например кликаешь на первый пункт, идет воспроизведение, потом на второй и второй накладывается на первый и мне кажется так будет с каждым пунктом.

Вопрос как же правильно остановить предыдущий и начать новый?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final String[] spisok = new String[]
                {getResources().getString(R.string.europa),
                        getString(R.string.topnews),
                        getString(R.string.diskoteka90)
                };

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spisok);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0){ playRadio1(); }
                if (position == 1){ playRadio2(); }
                if (position == 2){ playRadio3(); }
            }
        });
    }

   public void playRadio1() {

       String link1 = "http://ep128.hostingradio.ru:8030/ep128";
       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(link1));
       mediaPlayer.start();

   }

    public void playRadio2() {

        String link2 = "http://hls-01-europaplus-new.emgsound.ru/27/128/playlist.m3u8";
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(link2));
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед вызовом  `mediaPlayer.start()` проверить, не играет ли уже какой трек:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
         mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(link));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Дело в том что я уже пробовал так и при таком варианте, выдает ошибку `NullPointerException`

Comment: Это именно тот способ, который нужен. Других нет. NullPointerException возникает совсем по другой причине и на эту тему здесь 100500 вопросов. Только сегодня было минимум два.

Comment: И тем не менее свой вопрос я решил и ошибки нет и работает нормально

Comment: Так написал, будто решил каким-то другим способом :D

Comment: Просто я долго пытался найти решение, и вот он этот момент когда все получилось xD! Хочется рассказать всем!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void playRadio1() {

    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    String link1 = "http://ep128.hostingradio.ru:8030/ep128";
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(link1));
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```